# How to plot charts side by side with a forloop

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, matplotlib

i have the following code:

```
import pandas as pd
from pandas import datetime
from pandas import DataFrame as df
import matplotlib
from pandas_datareader import data as web
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import datetime
import numpy as np

stocks = 'GE','F' #<-- In this case there are just 2 symbols but this could be more 
start = datetime.date(2000,1,1)
end = datetime.date.today()

data = web.DataReader(stock, 'yahoo',start, end)

for stock in stocks:
    data.plot(y='Close')
plt.subplot(1,1,2) #<-- Trouble here
```

Here is my question. How can i plot all the symbols side by side inside the forloop?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here i have used the plot function of dataframe, Also i like plotting in different colors so i do this small trick.

[image]

```
#CODE
import pandas as pd
from pandas import datetime
from pandas import DataFrame as df
import matplotlib
from pandas_datareader import data as web
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import datetime
import numpy as np

colors = ["b",'g','r','c','m','y','k']

stocks = 'GE','F' #<-- In this case there are just 2 symbols but this could be more 
start = datetime.date(2000,1,1)
end = datetime.date.today()

data = web.DataReader(stocks, 'yahoo',start, end)

# THIS MAKES A GRID OF 1 ROW and len(stocks) COLUMN and figure size as (width, height) in inches.
fig, axs = plt.subplots(1, len(stocks), figsize=(30, 5))
i = 0

#iterate for each stock
for stock in stocks:
    # i'th close stock will plot on i'th axs (Note: Whatever be your grid)
    data["Close"][stock].plot(ax=axs[i],color=colors[i%len(colors)])
    i += 1

#show plot
plt.show()
```

Answer (score 4):

You can take the code above and specify `figsize` parameter.

```
fig, ax = plt.subplots(1, len(stocks), figsize=(20, 10))
```

If you want all of your plots on the same row, just modify the first parameter of `figsize` which is the length of the horizontal axis of the box that contains the subplots.

For example, if you want every plot to be 10x10 :

```
fig, ax = plt.subplots(1, len(stocks), figsize=(len(stocks)*10, 10))
```

Answer (score 2):

Specify the number of rows and columns to `plt.subplots()` like this:

```
stocks = ['GE','F']
fig,ax = plt.subplots(1,len(stocks))
```

And plot each subplot like this:

```
for i,stock in enumerate(stocks): 
    data = web.DataReader(stock,'yahoo',start,end) 
    ax[i].plot(data.index,data['Close'])
```

Result:
[image]

Comment: Thank for your detailed answer. The charts which is plotted is squeezed in 1 grid block so to say, where there would have been 1 chart, 2 are squeezed in. Is it possible to plot them side by side but each plot will take the space of 1 only instead of space being split ?

Comment: You can use the `figsize` argument: `plt.figure(figsize=[width, height])` to specify the size of the whole `figure`.

Answer (score 0):

You were almost correct. You should place subplot inside the for loop.

```py
n = 2 # number of stocks
for i, stock in enumerate(stocks):
    data.plot(y='Close')
    plt.subplot(1,n,i+1)
```

Note that we loop over the stocks, but also keep track of the current index in `i`. We use that index to decide where to place the plots.